# Why does Paul use different prepositions regarding the origin of the first and second humanity? (I Corinthians 15:47)

Tags: greek, 1-corinthians, paul

Paul states in I Corinthians 15:47 :

> ο πρωτος ανθρωπος εκ γης χοικος ο δευτερος ανθρωπος ο κυριος εξ ουρανου
>
> [TR - Beza, Stephens, Elzevir and Scrivener are all identical]
>
> The first man is of the earth, earthy: the second man is the Lord from heaven.[KJV]

Paul uses εκ in describing the origin of the first humanity but then uses εξ in describing the origin of the second humanity.

What does Paul's choice of preposition tell us about these different origins ?

Edit Note : Thanks to the answer, it is clear that there is *no difference* in the preposition, which is informative, that 'out of the earth' and 'out of heaven' are both used to express Adam's origin and the origin of the second humanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm do not have any formal education in Greek.

The word [ἐκ is changed in form only before a vowel to ἐξ](http://logeion.uchicago.edu/%E1%BC%90%CE%BA). It is similar to how in English "a" becomes "an" before a vowel. "a dog" but "an apple".

Comment: Probably the shortest answer you have ever needed to give. Thank you. My ignorance is lessened (slightly). +1 and accepted.